# PROLOG (How to postorder a multiway tree )

Tags: prolog, dcg, multiway-tree, postorder

I'm struggling with a Prolog homework like below,

Prolog uses general trees, not binary trees.   An example is

```
     a(b,c,d(e,f,g))   where root a has 3 kids, as does kid d.

 It is possible to define both preorder and postorder for general trees, 
 although inorder of course makes no sense.

 For this assignment we are interested in postorder, which is defined as
 follows:

   to 'visit' a tree in postorder, 
      you visit the subtrees of the root, in left to right order,
      in postorder, and then you visit the root

 Thus the example above would yield the following postorder traversal:

        b c e f g d a

  Write Prolog code which will perform a postorder traversal of a Prolog
 tree constant.   Hint: you might use 'univ', or its cousins.

 Sample dialog:

 ?- postorder(a(b,c,d(e,f,g))).
 b c e f g d a    true
```

Any help of this puzzle is appreciated.

Comment: It's homework? And, with homework, you're supposed to figure out the answer yourself. So, what have you written toward solving this yourself? Please don't ask someone on Stack Overflow to do that work for you; Instead, ask us to help with minor problems with the code you are writing.

Answer (score 3):

I give you a solution that works for a cleaner data representation, which works solely by pattern matching and does not require any `univ` etc. I *uniformly* present all trees in the form `tree(Node, Children)`. Your example can be written in this representation as:

```
example(T) :-
        T = tree(a, [tree(b,[]),
                     tree(c,[]),
                     tree(d, [tree(e,[]),
                              tree(f,[]),
                              tree(g,[])])]).
```

Now, as you are describing a *list* of nodes, consider using a DCG. For example:

```
postorder(tree(Node, Children)) -->
        postorder_(Children),
        [Node].

postorder_([]) --> [].
postorder_([C|Cs]) -->
        postorder(C),
        postorder_(Cs).
```

Example query with the above definitions and its result:

```
?- example(T), phrase(postorder(T), Ns).
T = tree(a, ...),
Ns = [b, c, e, f, g, d, a].
```

I leave it as a simple exercise to make this DCG work with your representation of trees (which I do not recommend, since you cannot describe solutions via pattern matching alone although that is clearly possible with a different representation, as I show above).

Answer (score 0):

```
tree :-
Tree= [1,
        [2,
       [4,
         [7, nil, nil],
         nil], 
       [5, nil, nil]],
        [3,
     [6,
       [8, nil, nil], 
       [9,nil, nil]], 
     nil]],

write('preorder    : '), preorder(Tree), nl,
write('inorder     : '), inorder(Tree), nl,
write('postorder   : '), postorder(Tree), nl,
write('level-order : '), level_order([Tree]),!.

preorder(nil).
preorder([Node, FG, FD]) :-
format('~w ', [Node]),
preorder(FG),
preorder(FD).


inorder(nil).
inorder([Node, FG, FD]) :-
inorder(FG),
format('~w ', [Node]),
inorder(FD).

postorder(nil).
postorder([Node, FG, FD]) :-
postorder(FG),
postorder(FD),
format('~w ', [Node]).


level_order([]).

level_order(A) :-
level_order_(A, U-U, S),
level_order(S).

level_order_([], S-[],S).

level_order_([[Node, FG, FD] | T], CS, FS) :-
format('~w ', [Node]),
append_dl(CS, [FG, FD|U]-U, CS1),
level_order_(T, CS1, FS).

level_order_([nil | T], CS, FS) :-
level_order_(T, CS, FS).


append_dl(X-Y, Y-Z, X-Z).
```

via Rosetta Code - [Tree Traversal in Prolog](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Prolog)

The code has preorder, inorder, postorder and level order.

Take a look at them all, you might find them useful.

Output:

```
?- tree.
 preorder    : 1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 9 
 inorder     : 7 4 2 5 1 8 6 9 3 
 postorder   : 7 4 5 2 8 9 6 3 1 
 level-order : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
true .
```

**Edit:** At the end of the `tree` query I added the `!` so it will stop the backtracking on the first `true.`. Otherwise after `true.`, if you typed `;` you would get `true.` again and again and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
postorder([]).
postorder(Tree):- Tree =..[Parent|Children] , myfun(Children), write(Parent),write(' ').
myfun([First|Next]):- atom(First), write(First), write(' '), myfun(Next).
myfun([First|Next]):- postorder(First),myfun(Next).
myfun([]).
```